# Adding large data in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have around 200,000 data in excel which is separated in per 15min for each day for two years. Now, I want to add for each day(including all the 15mins data at once) eg. 01/01/2014 to 12/31/2016. I did it using a basic formula (=sum(range)) but it is very time consuming. Can anyone help me find a easy way to resolve this problem?

Comment: can you provide a sample data set (even a few lines in a formatted table or google sheet )

Answer (score 0):

It's faster and more reliable to work with big data sets using [Ms Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) in which you can perform data analitics and process with single queries, or using [Power View](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rg37CyqUklY) of the dataset loaded into the datamodel that really works really fast.